# Vuetify groupable table, is there a way to edit the the group name format?

Tags: vuetify.js

The Vuetify table has an group-by prop, but instead of showing the header text it shows header value and then the group. Is there possible to change that?

What I'm looking for is like in the screenshot below, you can see the groups are like 'category: Candy'. The 'category' here is the header value. Is there a way to change it to 'Category' which would be the text?

```
 { text: 'Category', value: 'category', align: 'right' },
```

[image: Screenshot of Vuetify Table doc]

Answer (score 2):

I could not find an appropriate attribute for you to set, but what could be used is a predefined object in the [group.header slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-group.header):

```
<v-data-table :headers="headers" :items="desserts" item-key="name" sort-by="name" group-by="category" class="elevation-1" show-group-by>
  <template v-slot:group.header="{groupBy, group, isOpen, toggle, remove}">
    <td :colspan="headers.length">
      <v-icon @click="toggle">
        {{ isOpen ? 'mdi-minus' : 'mdi-plus' }}
      </v-icon>
      <span>{{customGroupNames[groupBy[0]]}} : {{group}}</span>
      <v-icon @click="remove">
        mdi-close
      </v-icon>
    </td>
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Then you have to set the `customGroupNames` variable in your component:

```
data() {
    return {
      customGroupNames: { "category": "Cat", "dairy": "Dairy" },
      headers: [...],
      dessserts: [...]
    }
}
```

You would essentially have to rebuild the group header row, but you will be able to display whatever you like.

Comment: Great!!! It worked for me modifying it in this way:

<template v-slot:[`group.header`]="{ groupBy, group, isOpen, toggle, remove }">